# Question about meaning of the words "goofy" and "support system nearby"

Tags: word-meaning

-Hi there!  I am a native Houstonian, moved out of state to get my college degree, but then came back.  My friends would describe me as sweet, loyal, caring and slightly **goofy** at times ;-).  My family and friends are very important to me, and I try to do what I can to maintain those relationships.  My immediate family lives in the area, so I like having that **support system nearby**.  A good chunk of my friends are married and have kids, so that limits the availability of them getting out to do things with me.

-Music is probably my biggest passion and I love going to concerts!  My usual is mostly Rock/Alternative, but it can vary depending on the day and what mood I'm in.  I enjoy going out to eat/drinks with friends, trying new places, photography, travelling, and going to games to name a few.  I enjoy going out on the town for drinks or dancing, but not one that will be at the clubs every weekend.  I prefer places where you can actually hear the people you're with.  I am also good with just having a low key evening at home, and at times rather would do that. I like watching most major sports, baseball in particular.  And yes, I am still an Astros fan! :-)   I also enjoy playing volleyball, sand or court, and currently am playing sand volleyball on a team through work.

-I am looking to find new friends to enjoy Houston with, but ultimately I am at the stage of my life where I am ready for a real relationship.  I am not interested in finding guys who want to just "hook up."  I would like someone that I can feel comfortable with, who is honest, compassionate, and thoughtful.  Laughter is essential in a relationship, so someone that can make me laugh is important (and not only with crude jokes/sayings).

-Feel free to send me a wink or email if you're interested or have questions to know more about me.

1. Does the word "goofy" is a slang meaning act like a retard person, do things without think? Having unusual habits? Which aspect of it does the slang goofy put emphasize on?
2. " support system nearby", I think it has two parts , part1 support system part 2 nearby. What is a support system and what kind of support system is a support system nearby? Any idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

1. I understand "goofy" pretty much as described in the second definition [here](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Goofy).  "Quirky" is a good synonym.  It doesn't necessarily mean unintelligent.  (Note that the word "retard" is generally considered derogatory.)
2. "Support system" as used here means a group of people (usually family/close friends) who are there to help you when you need cheering up, to provide "moral support," etc., see Merriam-Webster definition [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/support%20system).  And yes, by "nearby" she means that those she considers her "support system" live close to her.